# Microsoft VS Code: When I try to launch my program error "spawn php ENOENT" shows up

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am trying to run PHP code on Microsoft VS Code. When I click launch the only thing that happens is an error in the debug console saying:

> spawn php ENOENT

To fix this, I have put the dll file for XDebug into the ext folder. I copied php.ini-development into a new file called php.ini and in that file I added this to the end of the file.

```
zend_extension="[file path]"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

This changed nothing.

Then, I added an inbound rule for my firewall to allow inbound connections on port 9000. Still, nothing changed. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What fixed it for me, was adding this line to user settings:

```
"phpserver.phpPath": "c:\\Ampps\\php-7.1\\php.exe"
```

Your path may vary. (-> error occurs, because your php is not found)

phpserver: This is because I use the PHP Server extension. If you use a different extension, you need a different parameter.

Comment: Which "user settings", where are they?

Comment: @BrunoBieri Good question. I needed a moment to find it again. This helped me out: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings
Essentially, click the gear icon in the lower left or via menu: File>Preferences>Settings. To edit settings directly, you need to edit the file settings.json. Location: see link above. You can also enter "settings.json" in the "Search settings" field at the top of the settings form. You find a line "Edit in settings.json". There you go.

Answer (score 10):

I am using the [PHP_DEBUG](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug) extension and with a portable [laragon](https://jaist.dl.sourceforge.net/project/laragon/releases/4.0/laragon-wamp.exe?viasf=1) environment.
I had to make this change to my workspace settings / user settings

```
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable":"D:\\Share\\Dev\\Laragon\\bin\\php\\php-7.3.10-Win32-VC15-x64\\php.exe",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
```

Basically I had to add the runtimeExecutable line as defined by the [PHP_debug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug) extension.

I used [this guide](https://processwire.com/talk/topic/19089-how-to-use-xdebug-with-laragon-vscode/) to get working with vscode + xdebug + laragon

However I still have an issue, when running individual scripts, that the environment and extensions aren't properly loaded for the CLI

Comment: The guide you shared was what was really useful for me. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, I just needed to add the "runtimeExecutable" (and change the port which defaulted to 0) and everything's going good. +1

Answer (score 2):

For PHP-Debug users with similar issue:

Having worked for a long time, this stopped working for me recently (Oct 2021).

Usually within the `SPAWN ENOENT` error it will show the path it has set for PHP.

Although correct location was in PATH environment variable (which is used by default in the PHP-Debug extension), it was still giving error.

If you set the `runtimeExecutable` in settings explicity, that also failed.

The only thing that worked for me was to set the `runtimeExecutable` to simply `"PHP"`.

Answer (score 0):

One cause for this error could be a missing launch configuration in VS Code. You may try to add a `launch.json` in directory `.vscode`.

Here is the one I am using.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9003
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by setting the working directory. Seems to need to be set each tab.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using VsCode with XAMPP in ubuntu - linuxmint.

This VSCode settings **were not working**:

> ```
> "php.debug.executablePath": "/usr/bin/php",
> "php.validate.executablePath": "/usr/bin/php"
> ```

The reason in my case was that /usr/bin/php is a symbolic link to /opt/lampp/bin/php, and it seems that VSCode doesn't like it.
I got the **solution** changing the path to the original php executable in XAMPP:

> ```
> "php.debug.executablePath": "/opt/lampp/bin/php",
> "php.validate.executablePath": "/opt/lampp/bin/php"
> ```

Hope it helps.