# What's wrong with my xamppp - visual studio code setup?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xampp

I have Visual Studio Code and Xampp.
I have a file 'hello.php' with content: `<?php 'echo hello world';`
I  start debugging (F5) and get this message:

> Error: spawn php ENOENT
>      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
>      at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
>      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {
>    errno: 'ENOENT',
>    code: 'ENOENT',
>    syscall: 'spawn php',
>    path: 'php',
>    spawnargs: [ 'c:\xampp\htdocs\_PropertyRent\hello.php' ]
>   }

What's wrong?

Comment: Review this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49240957/microsoft-vs-code-when-i-try-to-launch-my-program-error-spawn-php-enoent-show)

Comment: also your echo wont be executed, because the string apostrophe is before the echo not after

Comment: I mis typed it here. I have echo "Hello world";

Comment: where do i find those "user settings" ?